# How to “try_files” on different domain using nginx?

Tags: nginx

How can i config try_files to "try" and search files on a different different domain?

what i've tried:

```
location ~ .flv$ { limit_req zone=one burst=2; root /; internal;

                            try_files
                                    /megastorage$uri
                                    @searchflv;
                            flv;
                            output_buffers 1 3m;
                            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
                            expires 0;
            }

            location @searchflv {
                            root /;

                            try_files
                                    http://video-1.domain.com$uri
                                    http://video-2.domain.com$uri;
                            aio on;
                            directio  4m;
                            directio_alignment 4k;
                            sendfile off;
                            flv;
                            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
                            expires 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

You cannot `try_files` several times on a different domain, you can only search locally, and then if the search fails, redirect to another site.  On such site, you can presumably redirect further, if needed, but that would be unrelated to the configuration at the present site.

Else, you might try some ideas expressed at https://serverfault.com/questions/202011/nginx-and-2-upstreams/485044#485044.